# Python 3.5 issue with int() with base 10

Tags: python

I know this question has been posted here many time but I really couldn't solve it so I decided to put my function and the correspoding error hoping that someone can spot the problem. My following function is written as a script for Mininet simulation (python-based simulation for SDN):

```
def rules_count_thread(threadName, net, period):
    fo = open("rules.txt", "w")
    for i in range(period):
        rCount = 0
        for s in net.switches:
            rStr = s.cmd('ovs-ofctl dump-tables ' + s.name + ' | grep classifier')
            rCount = rCount + int(rStr[rStr.rfind('=') + 1:])
        fo.write(str(time.time()) + ': ' + str(rCount) + '\n')
        time.sleep(1)
    fo.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function rules_count_thread at 0x7fc450195578>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./experiment.py", line 99, in rules_count_thread
    rCount = rCount + int(rStr[rStr.rfind('=') + 1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'table 0 ("classifier"):\r\n'
```

The problem is when I use `int()` but I tried to use `float()` and it does not work as well. I've been trying to google it but still I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either `rStr[rStr.rfind('=') + 1:]` is not doing what you think it is supposed to, or `rStr` is not formatted the way you expect it to be. You're not supplying an integer in string for to `int()`, you're supplying `'table 0 ("classifier"):\r\n'`. Print out `rStr` before you process it to see what it actually looks like, so you can fix your parsing. It looks like your parsing is complex enough that you may want to use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) instead of your current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `rStr` has a value of `'table 0 ("classifier"):\r\n'`.  That string obviously doesn't represent an integer.

Note that `rStr` also doesn't have an `=` in it so your `rStr.rfind('=') + 1` just comes out to `0`.  This leads me to believe that the string that you're working with isn't the string that you want.  e.g. perhaps you're trying to parse the header of a table when you really only want to operate on the rows.